# What is the behaviour if file_get_contents tries to read a file while its currently being written to

Tags: php

If I have two PHP scripts, one which writes to a file using file_put_contents and another which reads from the same file with file_get_contents.

If the file is being written to and I try and access it for reading at the same time, what behaviour should I expect? Will the read fail with an error? Will the read wait until the write is complete? Will the read get partial contents?

Comment: That's... pretty easy to test by yourself...

Comment: Try it and tell us :)

Comment: I guess it returns an empty string/false, since the file is used. Maybe you can use fopen and flock instead

Comment: According to this question and answer it will read what it can and return that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412870/php-can-you-read-a-file-that-has-an-exclusive-lock-on-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the source code

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/file.c#L522

If the stream can't be opened by [php_stream_open_wrapper_ex](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/file.c#L551) then you will get false back.
If your provided [seek position](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/file.c#L558) can't be read you'll get a false back

If that works it will try to copy the contents of the [stream to memory](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/file.c#L568) for the length shown

We see `php_stream_cpy_to_mem` defined in [php_streams.h](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/8d3f8ca12a0b00f2a74a27424790222536235502/main/php_streams.h#L462) which redefines `_php_stream_copy_to_mem` which we can find defined in [streams.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/cec091176cecd3f1efd553f4283fa7346184ad36/main/streams/streams.c)

Then we have the interesting part on [line 1411](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/cec091176cecd3f1efd553f4283fa7346184ad36/main/streams/streams.c#L1411)

```
    while ((len < maxlen) && !php_stream_eof(src)) {
```

So, as long as the file hasn't been read, and an EOF signal/marker wasn't encountered it will read. If the read value is empty it will stop reading further.

It will then return the result that was read until then.